# Program for ASCENDING ORDER using bubble sorting

Tags: java, bubble-sort

It is supposed to arrange the array members into ascending order. Can anyone please explain step by step process in bubble sort.

```
//bubble sorting technique to sort the  integer in ascending order
            int n = 5;
            int limit = n- 1;//elements from 0 to n-1
            boolean flag = false;//if it is true,swapping is done 
            int temp;// temporary variable
            for(int i=0 ; i<limit; i++){
            for(int j = 0;j<limit-i;j++){
            //if first element is bigger than second one , then swap
            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = temp;//true->swapping done
            flag = true;
            }
            if(flag==false) break;//no swapping,so come out
            else flag = false;//assign initial value
            }
            //display sorted array
            system.out.println("the sorted array is")
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            system.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
```

Input: `50 23 11 99 23`

Output: `11 23 23 50 99`

Comment: Don't spam tags. And bubblesort is explain ad infinitum on conservatively a half-million websites, [like **this** one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: [Bubble sort Animation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/54/Sorting_bubblesort_anim.gif)

Comment: I think your code works {50,23,11,99,23} -> {23,11,50,99,23} -> {11,23,50,99,23} -> {11,23, 50, 99, 23} -> {11, 23, 50, 99, 23}. Is it wrong?

Comment: yeah wrong  @square1001 my result is 11 23 23 50 99

Answer (score 0):

Your last end brace is on the wrong line so you're getting the`"the sorted array is"` output for every outer loop cycle. Move it up 3 lines:

```
      if (flag==false)
          break;
      else
          flag = false;
      }
 } // Move it here
 system.out.println("the sorted array is")
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 system.out.println(arr[i]);
```